# sum of determinants of $n$x$n$ created from all permutations of numbers $1..n^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

As the title says the task is to find the sum of determinants of $n$x$n$ created from all permutations of numbers $1..n^2$.
To be honest I don't even know where to get started, hints would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** For $n\geq 2$ exchanging the first two rows of the matrix changes the sign of the determinant.

> Try to pair up all $n \times n$ matrices whose entries are permutations of $1,\dots,n^2$ such that the sum of the determinants of each pair sum to $0$.